# How to set customer ID on invoice.paid event with STRIPE CLI

Tags: node.js, command-line, stripe-payments

I want to test the "invoice.paid" event with stripe CLI specifying the "custom ID" argument. When an invoice is submitted, I must check whether the payment has succeeded or failed in order to act accordingly on the right client.

If I don't use the right way to do it, I would like to know how to test the invoice.paid event in a local environment by specifying the customer ID.(cus_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx).

I tried this command line :

`stripe trigger invoice.paid --add invoice:customer=cus_xxxxxxxxxxxxx`

There must be something I'm doing wrong and/or that I didn't understand while going through the documentation. The result is always a different custom ID from the one I send as a parameter.

Finally, the question is :
How test invoice.paid event with a custom ID in parameter and retrieve it on my webhook?
Any help would be appreciated :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new file `invoice.paid.existing.json` (or any name you prefer), copy the content over from Stripe CLI's [invoice.paid fixture](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/blob/master/pkg/fixtures/triggers/invoice.paid.json).
2. Remove the [first "customer" fixture](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/blob/master/pkg/fixtures/triggers/invoice.paid.json#L6-L13), and replace all other fixture's `${customer:id}` to your own Id
3. Run `stripe fixtures invoice.paid.existing.json`

Reference: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/issues/295#issuecomment-592930683

Comment: Hey, I will test all that and I will validate your answer as soon as it works :). I also contacted stripe to find out why this command is not working, apparently they will fix the problem.

Comment: This work perfectly :). For information stripe replied that the command does not exist and that it is not planned to implement it:/.